# OpenCV: Removing surrounding from image

Tags: opencv

I have image with **a document in the middle** and with some surrounding (carpet, desk of the table, etc.)

[image]

**I would like to remove all surrounding and have just a document.** 
I tried threshold and adaptiveThreshold, but I didn't achieve much.

**So I would like to take samples of the surrounding and base on that remove all surrounding.**

Is that somehow possible in OpenCV?

Answer (score 8):

## Gerneral infos

- The background in the current scenario can be interpreted as noise
- The overall image is not homogeneously illuminated (left side is brighter than right side). This complicates things if we want to use thresholds.
- The document has a very distinct color (gray/white)
- The document is largely homogeneous
- The shadow of the document may cause problems
- If the scenario/background can change this problem becomes much harder to solve

## General tips

- The contour size can be either its length (this only works if

> cv::ContourApproximationModes::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE

is used) or its area 
(just draw the contour filled and count the drawn pixels - this is the most reliable way to extract the area information).

### Solving the problem

There are multiple ways to solve this specific problem:

- Threshold, apply morphology, contour search, select largest contour. No samle image containing the background is needed (except maybe for initial parametrization).
- Noise detection (simple diff between filtered and unfiltered image, per-pixel neighborhood analysis for standard deviation, etc. - define threshold for max noise and then apply cv::threshold()) 
  for background classification, then classify foreground, apply morphology, perform contour search, select largest contour.
  Sample image of background could be used to determine threshold for an initial parameter guess.
- Edge detection (Sobel / Scharr / etc. - define threshold for max edge intensity and then apply cv::threshold()) for background classification, then classify foreground, apply morphology, perform contour search, select largest contour.
  Sample image of background could be used to determine threshold for an initial parameter guess.
- Color detection/classification for either background (brownish color) or foreground (gray/white), apply morphology, perform contour search, select largest contour.
  Color detection should be done in either HSV or LAB color space. 
  To have a robust approach, the color detection should ignore difference in brightness (otherwise the shadow of the document may not be identified as background) 
  and at the same time should exclude too dark and too bright pixels from color classification altogether.
  Sample image of background could be used to determine typical background colors but since there are grayish color tones in the background and the object itself is gray/white
  one should probably extract the colors manually.

---

To generally solve this problem is rather difficult.
For example, if you use color detection to find the gray/white document but change the scenario to a background that is gray and less bright than the document, the color
detection and classification will fail since we will use gray to detect the background as well as the foreground.
In this case the threshold approach will work much better.

So a fully automated process will be difficult to accomplish.
I think you will have to make the background classification strategy interchangeable so you can easily change it to make it fit the scenario.
Of course it's possible to implement some kind of heuristic, e.g. a sample image from the background could be analyzed regarding its noise or standard deviation, etc.
If there is a significant amount of noise then the approach of noise detection/classification is feasible.
If there is almost zero noise but a homegeneous brightness or color that is distinct from the document, the threshold or color detection/classification approach is suited best.

Here is some code for the first method (simple threshold) that completely extracts the document:

```
void drawRotatedRect(cv::Mat& drawing, cv::RotatedRect& rr, cv::Scalar color)
{
    cv::Point2f points[4];
    rr.points(points);
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        cv::line(drawing, points[j], points[(j + 1) % 4], color, 1, 8);
    }
}

// Adapted from http://answers.opencv.org/question/14807/fill-an-image-with-the-content-of-rotatedrect/
void drawRotatedRectFilled(cv::Mat& image, cv::RotatedRect rRect, cv::Scalar color) 
{
    cv::Point2f vertices2f[4];
    cv::Point vertices[4];
    rRect.points(vertices2f);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
    {
        vertices[i] = vertices2f[i];
    }
    cv::fillConvexPoly(image, vertices, 4, color);
}

void testDocumentExtraction()
{
    // Load image
    std::string path = "./Testdata/Stackoverflow 1/";
    std::string filename = "1.jpg";
    std::string fqn = path + filename;
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(fqn, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);

    auto imageSize = img.size();

    // Convert to gray
    cv::Mat imgGray;
    cv::cvtColor(img, imgGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    // Threshold with OTSU
    cv::Mat imgBin;
    int thresholdFlags = cv::ThresholdTypes::THRESH_BINARY + cv::ThresholdTypes::THRESH_OTSU;
    cv::threshold(imgGray, imgBin, 0.0, 255.0, thresholdFlags);

    // Morph
    int erosionSize = 3;
    int erosionType = cv::MORPH_RECT;
    cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(erosionType,
        cv::Size(2 * erosionSize + 1, 2 * erosionSize + 1),
        cv::Point(erosionSize, erosionSize));

    int nbMorphIterations = 2;
    cv::Mat imgMorphed;
    imgBin.copyTo(imgMorphed);
    for (int i = 0; i < nbMorphIterations; ++i)
    {
        cv::erode(imgMorphed, imgMorphed, element);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        cv::dilate(imgMorphed, imgMorphed, element);
        cv::erode(imgMorphed, imgMorphed, element);
    }

    // Find contours.
    // TODO: if we find more than one, use the largest one
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    cv::Mat tempMat;
    imgMorphed.copyTo(tempMat);
    cv::findContours(tempMat, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::ContourApproximationModes::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    // Get contour of our (potential) object
    auto contourOfObject = contours.at(0);
    // Build object oriented bounding box (since the object is rectangular but potentially rotated).
    auto oobb = cv::minAreaRect(contourOfObject);

    // Draw contour or rotated rect filled to get a mask for the object.
    // To have smoother roi borders, use rotated rect
    cv::Mat maskForObject = cv::Mat::zeros(imageSize, CV_8U);
    //cv::drawContours(maskForObject, contours, 0, cv::Scalar(255), cv::FILLED);
    drawRotatedRectFilled(maskForObject, oobb, cv::Scalar(255));

    // Draw the rotated rect in red color
    cv::Mat drawing;
    img.copyTo(drawing);
    drawRotatedRect(drawing, oobb, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255));

    // Copy only the object from input image
    cv::Mat imgWithOnlyTheObject = cv::Mat::zeros(imageSize, CV_8UC3);
    img.copyTo(imgWithOnlyTheObject, maskForObject);

    // Show all the stuff
    cv::imshow("img", img);
    cv::imshow("maskForObject", maskForObject);
    cv::imshow("imgWithOnlyTheObject", imgWithOnlyTheObject);
    cv::imshow("imgGray", imgGray);
    cv::imshow("imgBin", imgBin);
    cv::imshow("imgMorphed", imgMorphed);
    cv::imshow("drawing", drawing);

    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

### Images

Color image
[image: 1]
Gray image
[image: 2]
Thresholded image
[image: 3]
Morphed image
[image: 4]
Object oriented bounding box of largest contour
[image: 5]
Object mask from object oriented bounding box
[image: 6]
Object extracted from original image
[image: 7]